# C# playing multiple sounds at once with P/Invoke

Tags: c#, audio, pinvoke

I am writing (translating) my java game engine into `C#`. Now I have got to play multiple sounds at once. I was targeting only the windows platform and need to support these formats.

- WAV (PCM)
- MIDI
- AIFF
- AU

For learning purposes, I want to use `P/Invokes` for this. Are there any `P/Invokes` which does these things? Searching google always pointed the `SoundPlayer` class but which is not what I need.

Thanks

Comment: Don't want to bother, but there are very good libraries out there easily make it possible to play multiple audio files.

Answer (score 0):

Check [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/) page.

Below you have some links:

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/winmm.playsound

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll/playsound.html

Comment: He already knows that SoundPlayer isn't useful.  Which uses PlaySound().  Linking to pinvoke that only works on Windows Mobile is particularly unhelpful.